# Android Development using Head First

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an android app to check whether the string entered by user is palindrome or not.I am using charAt function to extract every character from string.But it shows the error that 'the method char(int) is undefined for the type View.OnClickListener() {}'.
I have written the code as:-

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str=input.getText().toString();
            String st="";
            int i=1,l=str.length();
            while(i>l)
            {
            st=st+charAt(i);
            i--;
            }   
            if(st.equalsIgnoreCase(str)==true)
                disp.setText("Your string is Palindrome");
            else
                disp.setText("Your string is Not Palindrome");
        }
    });
```

Plz. help me out with this charAt function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `str.charAt(i)`

What is happening is that you are saying `charAt()` without specifying a class. The program then resorts to the class/interface that you are within. Currently, you're in the `View.OnClickListener()` interface which doesn't have a `charAt()` method. You need to specify which object you want to get the character from.

Comment: Thank u you have explained me well I have got the mistake and my app is running

Comment: Sir, I am in my initial stage of android development can you tell me what I have to do to become a good android programmer......

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept the answer so that others may be helped as well. To learn more about Android Development, check out the Android Developer Tutorials and also at Stack Overflow if you ever run into any more issues.